# iPhone AVCapture: accessing the CVPixelBuffer is slow

Tags: iphone, performance, avcapture

I've been using CoreGraphics to create a bitmap context around the pixel buffer and extract an image using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, then using `CGContextDrawImage` to draw that image in another (grayscale) buffer.
Profiling shows that `CGContextDrawImage` takes a lot of time, so I thought I would avoid it by accessing the original `CVPixelBuffer` directly. But it turns out that that's much slower!

I guess that buffer lies in some special memory area that is slow to access for some reason.

What's the fastest way to get those pixels into a place where I can process them quickly, then?